# Как получить все заголовки на странице h1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно вывести в файл все заголовки со страницы

Я пробовал получить контент всех заголовков таким образом:

```
var headings = $('h1').map(t => t.outerText)
```

Но у коллекции всех нодов нету таких методов для работы с массивами как map, join и тд.

Как можно это реализовать ?

Comment: А вы в курсе, что `h1` только один раз должен быть на странице?

Comment: Я использую генератор для документации, там h1 используетьсяне один раз, да и этот скрипт я бы хотел применять к другим заголовкам так же (h2, h3 ... )

Comment: @DaemonHK, в спецификации ничего такого не говорится.

Comment: @Qwertiy спецификации чего? HTML5? SEO-шники и гугл вам скажут как надо)

Comment: Да, html5. Seo'шники идут лесом.

Comment: @Qwertiy угу, а потом сайт проседает в выдаче из-за политики гугл))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
/* jQuery */
console.log($('h1').map((i, h) => $(h).text()).toArray())

/* native */
console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('h1'), h => h.textContent))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<h1>Ещё заголовок</h1>
<h1>Третий</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это же jQuery, у него все есть

```
$('h1, h2, h3').map((index, item) => item.outerText)
```

Comment: Ну нафига откапывать это сомнительное новое свойство, которое вообще ничего полезного не добавляет?

Comment: @Qwertiy вы о чем?

Comment: Об `outerText`.

Comment: Ну это не я откапал, а автор. Вникать не стал, дал что просил

Answer (score 0):

На чистом js - сделал прямо в консоли браузера

```
var h1_collection = document.getElementsByTagName('H1'),
    result = [];
for(var i=0; i<h1_collection.length;i++ ){
    result.push(h1_collection[i].innerText)
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Теперь `innerText`...